# Java clearing a list by creating a new instance

Tags: java, performance, list, arraylist, new-operator

I was looking through Java code, and I came across this code:

```
list = new ArrayList();
uselist(list);

if (condition)
   list = new ArrayList();
```

What's the use of this, as opposed to simply using the clear() method of ArrayLists.

is using the new command to clear a list is ok and is it faster than clearing a list ?

i am using java version 1.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do note that clearing and re-instantiating a list is not the same thing!

Consider this example:

```
a = new ArrayList();
a.add("Hello")
b = a;
a = new ArrayList();   // a is now empty while b contains hello!
```

Versus

```
a = new ArrayList();
a.add("Hello")
b = a;
a.clear();            // Both a and b are now empty.
```

If the side-effects (shared references) are not an issue, then it is just two ways of clearing a list. It should probably not be a performance issue unless this is called millions of times.

Comment: and if it is called million of times which will be faster ?

Comment: I have no idea. When faced with a potential optimisation like that I'd probably have to benchmark it. It probably depends quite a lot on the circumstances such as list sizes, whether the retention of the (larger) internal arrays of the ArrayList after clear() will affect the perf of the application negatively etc. I do suspect the differences are rarely noticable, and that it is almost surely an unnecessary optimization either way.

Answer (score 9):

No, they don't do the same thing. The method clear() clears an *existing* list - anything which still has a reference to the list and looks at it later will see that it's empty.

The approach with the *new* keyword, changes the value of the `list` variable but does nothing to the existing `ArrayList` *object* - so if anything else has a reference to the same object, they won't see any changes.

Answer (score 3):

If the list is used elsewhere calling `clear()` might cause side effects.
However, if that is not the case, I'd say that creating a new list instead of clearing the old one *might* be faster (however, probably for huge lists only, since `ArrayList`'s `clear()` just iterates over the elements and set's them as  `null`), but most likely it's just a matter of programming style.

Comment: I have the exact opposite experience with side effects. The new operator caused hibernate to flip out when the list what connected thru a proxy to hibernate.

Comment: @Farmor yes, in fact both approaches might cause side effects, but assuming Hibernate and similar reflection using libraries are not used here, a `new` might cause less side effects (meaning the list that might still be in use elsewhere might otherwise "suddenly" be empty).

Comment: It causes a problem in Hibernate because Hibernate (as well mostly any other JPA implementation) replaces you List with another instance, created and managed by Hibernate itself, so that it can track modifications and load elements in the list lazily as they are required instead of loading everything upfront. In that case, since the list is shared between you and hibernate, you have to call .clear() and have the positive side effect of telling Hibernate you are actually removing those elements.

Comment: @Simone That's true. In the case of Hibernate you'd have a proxied list, however, I assume no Hibernate is used here.

Comment: no no, Hibernate is never mentioned here, I was just speculating on it :D

Answer (score 2):

Wether it is the same or not it depends on what uselist(...) does internally with the list.

For example, suppose you have the following code in uselist :

```
public void uselist(List l) {
    this.mylist = l;
}
```

In that case, your code will create a new list and not touch this.mylist . If instead you call .clear() on it, you are clearing that same list.

Answer (score 0):

The difference can be fatal and hard to see.  For example `hibernate` will flip out of you use `list = new ArrayList()`; and then try to update the list in the db but it works just fine with clear() as hibernate then can see the connection.

```
clear() // operates on your old object 

list = new ArrayList(); // list will be a new object the old will be GCed
```